# Font awesome book reader icon not loading

Tags: html, fonts, icons, font-awesome

Im trying to use font awesome icon on my page beside the navbar brand. But for some reason its not loading. Need Help

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/e017101791.js"></script>
```

This is the script tag that font awesome mailed me and the one i'm using in my code

In the font awesome website the html for book-reader icon is

```
<i class="fas fa-book-reader"></i>
```

But in my code if i use 'fas' with 's' its not working so i had to write the class name as 'fa fa-book-reader'

In the footer I'm using facebook, twitter, instagram icon they are all loading perfectly after writing their class names as 'fa fa-facebook' instead of 'fab fa-facebook'.

.HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-book-reader fa-3x mx-3"></i>
            Books</a>
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
            aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="mr-auto"></div>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"
                  >Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
                >
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Course</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Price</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="nav-link">Pages</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#" class="">Generic</a>
                    <a href="#">Element</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Fact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

My Webpage Pic

[image]

Expected Webpage Output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
```

Use this cdn type and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Include this in the head section of your page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css">
```